# Correct Amount of Spaces with concatenated person's name in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, concatenation, varchar, spaces

Here is my SQL as I have it now.  The first and last name should never be missing because they are required on the interface with validation.  However, if the middle initial is missing, I don't want two spaces in the result; I just want one space.  I could put a case statement in, but that seems like overkill if SQL already has a function for this purpose.  Does anyone know if there is a function for this purpose?  What would the code look like?

```
SELECT ISNULL(contact.firstname, '') 
         + ' ' 
         + ISNULL(contact.middleinitial, '') 
         + ' ' 
         + ISNULL(contact.lastname, '')
FROM dbo.contact
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT
 ISNULL(contact.firstname, '') + 
 ISNULL(' ' + contact.middleinitial + ' ', ' ') + 
 ISNULL(contact.lastname, '')
```

However, you either should remove ISNULL for firstname, lastname (defined NOT NULL?) or add some trims

```
SELECT
 LTRIM(RTRIM(
   ISNULL(contact.firstname, '') + 
    ISNULL(' ' + contact.middleinitial + ' ', ' ') + 
    ISNULL(contact.lastname, '')
 ))
```

Comment: Ah very clever!  I should have known that ISNULL will return NULL even if you append the blank spaces to both sides.. so the ISNULL function will return null in that case.  I was also trying to use TRIM... and didn't realize you must nest both the left and right trim into one function.  Nice work!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server 2012 and up you can use CONCAT function:

```
    SELECT  CONCAT(contact.firstname, ' ' + contact.middleinitial, ' ' + contact.lastname)
    FROM dbo.contact
```

If **middleinitial** is null then appending space to null value will result in null value and CONCAT will skip this null value during concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT REPLACE(ISNULL(contact.firstname, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(contact.middleinitial, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(contact.lastname, '')
               ,'  ',' ')
FROM dbo.contact
```